# what's the main difference between B-Rep and Parametric representation

Tags: spline, cad, solidworks, brep

For solid modeling, I heard besides B-Rep, there is parametric representation. Is there any difference between those two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A BRep is one way (among many) of representing objects in a computer.  Other ways of representing objects are voxels and meshes.

The concept of parametric modeling is independent of the representation of object, although it is intimately associated with it.  I think the easiest way to visualize the relationship between the two is to think of a parametric modeler as a machine that accepts two inputs:

1. **The recipe for a model**.  An example recipe is: "a block with dimensions `length`, `width` and `height`, with a hole in the center of the top face of radius `.25*width`.
2. **The values for the parameters**.  For the previous example the values might me `length=10 cm`, `width=5 cm`, `height=3 cm`.  `radius` doesn't need to be specified because it is given by the relationship `radius = .25*width`.

[image: Parametric Modeler]

Given the recipe and set of values for the parameters, the modeler tries to compute a model.  If it succeeds, the output is a model that may be represented as a b-rep, but could alternatively be something else such as a voxel or mesh model.

Currently most commercial parametric modelers work with B-reps.

Of course much of the software to implement a parametric modeler is focused on providing tools to specify the recipe, often as a feature list (feature-based modeling), or as relationships (aka "constraints") between objects (variational modeling) or both.  These tools are considered part of the parametric modeler, but the heart of the modeler is a compute operation similar to what I described.